# How to pass the query string arguments to ES Nest client for validating multiple test results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nunit

> 

Hi,

I need to pass the ES query string to Nest client for multiple test cases.
[Test1]
[Test2]
But query strings mentioned in Testcase are not updating.
it always updated as empty only.
Any suggestions to fix this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          

            string value1 = "";
            string value2 = "";

            USTests.ComparitiveTests(value1, value2);
            
            
            
            public class USTests
    {
 

        [Test]
        [TestCase("sales.state: TX", "sales.state: CA")]
        public static void ComparitiveTests(string value1, string value2)
        {
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("xxxx"));

            var indexName = "test-indexName";

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            var searchRespone1 = client.Search<Sales>(
               (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
               .Query(q => q.Match(m => m
               .Query(value1)
               )
               )
               )
               );

            Console.WriteLine(searchRespone1);

            var searchRespone2 = client.Search<Sales>(
               (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
               .Query(q => q.Match(m => m
               .Query(value2)
               )
               )
               )
               );

            Console.WriteLine(searchRespone2);
```

Comment: You have a main, which executes your test method. That's not the normal way of running NUnit tests. Unfortunately, I can't tell if you are a beginner with NUnit making a beginner's mistake or if you are trying to do something sophisticated, which is beyond my understanding... :-) Please help us understand what you are trying to do here so we can better help you.

Comment: Hi Charlie,

I need to pass query string arguments as follows
[a] [b]



This method "ComparitiveTests(string value1, string value2)"

runs the ES query using 1st argument[a] and count value is stored.
runs the ES query using 2st argument[b] and count value is stored.
Check whether the 1st count is greater than the 2nd one using Assert method and mark the testcase as passed or failed.

Likewise I am planning to pass 100 query string as test arguments and validates the condition.
Thanks

Comment: My question was... Why are you calling the tests yourself from your Main() method rather than using an NUnit runner, which knows how to interpret the attributes you are using?

Comment: yes, I realised that thing and able to run the tests from Nunit runner.

Now I have a following 2 questions
I have A.cs file with 5 unit tests and B.cs file with 5 unit tests

Q1. how to configure these unit tests files to the project.
Q1.  I need to send an email that how many tests are passed. How to add the mailer service to this unit tests files.

Posted a separate question also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655205/how-to-consolidate-the-unit-test-results-to-a-email

Thanks in Advance